# Maven: Pom file - externalizing dependency versions to a properties file

Tags: maven

I'd like to externalize the dependency versions in the POM file to a properties file.

Example: `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>${externalized.junit.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

`abc.properties`

```
externalized.junit.version=4.8.2
```

Can this be done? If so, what would be the best way to do it?

Comment: Why? What is the use case?

Comment: No you can't do that. What problem are you trying to solve? You could specify it as a system property but that's not a good way to have a reproducible build.

Comment: Does it make sense?

Comment: no you cant. an option might be creating a "bom" file and use the import mechanism to distribute the same versions: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Importing_Dependencies

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you cannot do that.

When you're launching a Maven command on a project, the first action it takes is creating the effective model of the project. This notably means reading your POM file, reasoning with activated profiles, applying inheritance, performing interpolation on properties... all of this to build the final Maven model. This work is done by the [Maven Model Builder](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-model-builder/) component, whose entry point is the [`ModelBuilder`](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-model-builder/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/building/ModelBuilder.html) interface, and exit point is the [`Model`](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-model/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/Model.html) class.

The process of building the model is quite complicated, with a lot of steps divided in possibly 2 phases, but the crux of the issue here is simple: at the end of that step, there is a valid effective model to be used by Maven. Which means that all dependencies must have valid group ids, artifact ids, versions; that there are no duplicate dependencies, no plugin execution's with the same ids, etc. ([refer to the model description](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-model/maven.html)).

Take note that during the model building, [interpolation](http://maven.apache.org/components/ref/3.3.9/maven-model-builder/#Model_Interpolation) is happening, meaning that if a property is available at that time, and it was used, like `${myProperty}`, then it will be replaced with its corresponding value. Among the properties available are:

- POM content, like `${project.version}` or `${project.artifactId}`;
- `${project.basedir}`, which corresponds to the directory where the `pom.xml` is;
- user properties set on the command line with the `-D` switch (like `-DmyProperty=myValue`);
- any properties set directly in the POM file, inside the `<properties>` element;
- several built-in Maven properties, like `${maven.build.timestamp}`, which represents the date/time at which the build started, or `${maven.version}` for the current Maven version;
- Java system properties, as returned by [`System.getProperties()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties--)
- environment variables;
- and finally properties set [inside the `settings.xml` file](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-settings/settings.html).

The critical point point here, is that the version of dependencies must be valid when the effective model is built. This is the only way to make sure the dependency graph is stable and consistent during the build.

This is exactly what is failing here: you would want Maven to be able to read versions inside a properties file, so it means binding a plugin to a specific phase of the lifecycle to read that file and somehow refer to the properties read using a standard Maven properties. Trouble is, this would all be happening after the model is already built, so it is too late for that. All of this process is happening before the [build lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) has even started; no chance to invoke a plugin before that.

This also implies that it would work if you were to define the property as a command-line property (since, as outlined above, it is available during the interpolation process when building the model). But that is not a best practice: specifying dependency version as a command-line property makes the build very hard to reproduce. Better to specify it as a Maven property inside the `<properties>` element of the POM, or to make use of the [`<dependencyManagement>`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management) scheme in a parent POM or also [importing a BOM](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Importing_Dependencies).

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* need something like this, the easiest way would be to write a shell script (or some other short command line program) that copies the pom, replaces the specified properties in the pom and calls maven.

But as was said before: Probably there are more Maven-like ways to achieve what you want to achieve.

Comment: There aren't, at certain things maven just really f-ing sucks :)