# pom.xml is not able to read properties from external property file

Tags: java, xml, maven

I have a pom.xml and i have defined a property in it which is being referred from an external file -

Please Find my pom.xml below :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.src</groupId>
    <artifactId>common</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>common</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <scm>
        <connection>scm:svn:http://127.0.0.1/dummy</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://127.0.0.1/dummy</developerConnection>
        <tag>HEAD</tag>
        <url>http://127.0.0.1/dummy</url>
    </scm>

    <properties>
        <salcommon.version>${common-version}</salcommon.version>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>secureaccesslnk-maven</id>
            <url>https://nexus-maven/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
        <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>secureaccesslnk-maven-release</id>
            <url>https://nexus-maven-release/</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>secureaccesslnk-maven-snapshot</id>
            <url>https://nexus-maven-release/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>sal-logging</artifactId>
            <version>${salcommon.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>sal-auditor</artifactId>
            <version>${salcommon.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                    <include>**/*.tmpl</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                    <include>**/*.tmpl</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
                <artifactId>wagon-webdav-jackrabbit</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-beta-7</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <files>
                <file>common.version.properties</file>
              </files>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.7.4.201502262128</version>
                <configuration>
                    <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</destFile>
                    <append>true</append>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The common.version.properties details are below :-

```
common-version=3.0.1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Even though i have defined the plugin to read the property from external file .The property ${common-version} is not getting replaced at runtime when i am doing mvn clean install

Error - dependencies.dependency.version' for com.common
e a valid version but is '${common-version}'. @ line 107, column 13

I have tried to search the net a lot but none of the resolution worked for me.Please help!

Comment: What is the reason not to put the version into the pom file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, it is not possible to do what you're attempting to do (i.e. externalizing the version of an artifact). This is simply because Maven needs the whole dependency set before any plugin runs / before you're reading stuff from your file (it's a chicken-and-egg situation).

Answer (score 1):

Not Sure why you want to externalize jar version.

IF you want version of all jar files at same location and should be consistence across all projects, Then you can use  dependencyManagement tag provided my maven.

Add all you common dependency in parent pom and in child projects only specify dependency without version

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, it is not possible to do what you're attempting to do (i.e. externalizing the version of an artifact).
This is simply because Maven needs the whole dependency set before any plugin runs / before you're reading stuff from your file (it's a chicken-and-egg situation).

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40114869/maven-pom-file-externalizing-dependency-versions-to-a-properties-file) seems to support this statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a BOM POM and use it as a parent in your main POM. That way you have the properties in an external file.

BOM POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <properties>
    <common-version>3.0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</common-version>
  </properties>
</project>
```

In your main POM, you add the parent declaration:

```
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
  </parent>
```