# Error import libraries from properties file on pom.xml

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, pom.xml, maven-plugin

I'm trying to move my versions from pom.xml to a properties file, however when doing that, the import fails.

My pom.xml is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.trial</groupId>
    <artifactId>books</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <files>
                            <file>${basedir}/versions.properties</file>
                            </files>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- SPRING -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        ...
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Although no error is shown on pom.xml, the import has start failing (it was working fine when the properties where set on the pom.xml):

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
```

throws:

> Error:(6, 52) java: package
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation does not exist

The versions.properties looks like:

```
springframework.version = 5.0.1.RELEASE
```

What is going on? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40114869/maven-pom-file-externalizing-dependency-versions-to-a-properties-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven: Pom file - externalizing dependency versions to a properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40114869/maven-pom-file-externalizing-dependency-versions-to-a-properties-file)

Answer (score 0):

You know you can use things like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.trial</groupId>
    <artifactId>books</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
       <springframework.version>5.0.1.RELEASE</springframework.version>
    </properties>    

    <dependencies>
        <!-- SPRING -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        ...
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

There is no advantage is externalize the versions into a property file.

Comment: Yes I know, this is the case that I said that is working fine. But we want to externally configure more than one project with same versions, so the best way to do that is by creating a versions.properties file

Comment: If you like to use it for more than one project use a corporate parent pom and use dependencyManagement instead ...or create a bill of materials (BOM)...inparticular related to spring. Spring already has bom for such purposes...

Comment: I'll take a look to DependencyManagement. Thank you