# Share dependency versions between Maven (pom.xml) and Gradle (build.gradle)

Tags: maven, gradle, dependency-management

I have projects built by Maven and Gradle. Is there a way to define dependency versions in a text file, e.g.:

```
.
|-- dep-versions.properties
|
|-- proj-by-gradle
|   |-- build.gradle
|   `-- settings.gradle
|
`-- proj-by-maven
    `-- pom.xml
```

Is there an easy way to specify in `dep-versions.properties`, something like:

```
com.google.guava:guava = 26.0-jre
org.apache.commons:commons-pool2 = 2.5.0
```

And then use these versions in both the `pom.xml` and `build.gradle`?

Comment: You will be able to do that for the Gradle build using Gradle properties, but for Maven this does not seem possible, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40116146/6899896

Comment: @M.Ricciuti Thanks for the link, that answers the Maven part of the question. I guess I'll accept the answer from Rene Groeschke then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a BOM pom (Bill of materials) and use it in both builds. Support for importing maven BOM files was added to Gradle in version 4.6: https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/release-notes.html#bom-import